# AND statement on Android Programming

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

How to make AND stetement in this source code work? There is no error, but when it run, the buttonNext still invisible. I want it can be visible.

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) {
                  if( buttonD.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() &&
                              buttonO.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() &&
                              buttonG.getId() == ((Button)v).getId() ){
                      buttonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
    }
```

Is it wrong or something missed? Thanks for the answer..

Comment: You want OR "||".  The button ID can only be one of them, so it's always going to be false because it can't be all three.

Comment: `if v == D AND v == O AND v == G { do something }` - you probably mean `OR`?

Comment: No, I want AND. So I want all statement fulfilled to make buttonNext visible. if only one or two statement fulfilled, I want it still invisible.

Comment: The only case when the id of one view equals to 3 other views, is that you manually set the id of `buttonD`, `buttonO`, and `buttonG` instead of using R.id.xxxxx. Is this your case?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I've already set the id manually to make a textview visible. And I want to set them again to make buttonNext visible. I just want buttonNext will be visible when buttonD, buttonO, and buttonG are clicked, so it will be visible if you click all three button. if you just click one or two button, it will be still invisible.

Comment: @nichi Do you mean that buttonNext will only be visible when the other 3 buttons are being pressed **simultaneously**?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Not simultaneously, but one by one. for example, you press buttonD, and then you press buttonG, and then you press buttonO. after you press all of them one by one, buttonNext will be visible.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I've already post all of my current code in a new question, because I can't post it here. please check it. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one mate:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
              if( buttonD.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
                          buttonO.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE &&
                          buttonG.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ){
                  buttonNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking it wrongly. The `onClick` method does not store previous data, i.e. you cannot know what is pressed before the current view. You can use some flags to store it manually.

```
private boolean clickedBtnD;
private boolean clickedBtnO;
private boolean clickedBtnG;

public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.btnD:
            clickedBtnD = true;
            // Set your button to visible too?
            break;
        case R.id.btnO:
            clickedBtnO = true;
            // Set your button to visible too?
            break;
        case R.id.btnG:
            clickedBtnG = true;
            // Set your button to visible too?
            break;
        case R.id.btbNext:
            if(clickedBtnD && clickedBtnO && clickedBtnG) {
                buttonNext.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

All you need to do is to use this OnClickListener for all 4 buttons.

Comment: I've already follow your source code, but the buttonNext still invisible. Am I put it in the wrong place or what?

Comment: I've already post all of my current code in a new question, because I can't post it here. please check it. Thanks..